# debug.keystore problem

Tags: android, google-maps

For google map I generated MD5 fingerprint and get a api key.Due to my pc's time problem my debug.keystore was expired. So I deleted my debug.keystore . When I start eclipse debug.keystore was again generated. That api key was not working .So I generate api key second time. But still it is not working??

here is my main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent">

```
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my menifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"></uses-library>
    <activity android:name=".geo_loc"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


</application>
```

please help me out .....

Comment: Post your xml file for the layout that MapView is using. And post your manifest xml file

Comment: have a look at the answer, you will need these things based on what you posted

Answer (score 0):

For the layout that you call with mapview, (the one that you use to display your map) you need the following lines in your XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="0QoAJH8MAJvwqVDz6NcijUjWg8JBSEy29yjqGPg"
/>
```

Notice the API key

In you Manifest XML file you will need the following line that is inside the application tag and outside the activity tag

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

You will also need the following Permission in your manifest. Make sure it is outside the application tag

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

That should do it